# a href link inside iframe ie11 not working

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-11, anchor

I have a couple of links (anchor href) inside an iframe, they work fine in almost all browsers, except ie11.

The links contain the rel=“noopener noreferrer” but still clicking on the link won’t work, it doesn’t open the link.

Does anyone have encountered the same and how did you solve it?

Comment: I suggest you press the `F12` key in the IE 11 browser and go to the **Console** tab in the developer tools. Then after try to click on the link, see whether it displays an error or warning message in the console. If you see any error message then please try to inform us about that. It may give some idea about the cause of the issue.

Comment: There were no errors showing, already checked that. Thats the weird part.

Comment: It seems that IE11 is blocking the links, so they won’t do anything.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, try to lower down the level of security settings for the relevant zone and restart the machine. After that again try to test the issue with the IE browser.

Comment: Its not just me, and not happening in browser edge. Its only happening with ie11

Comment: Can you please inform us, what result you get for testing the issue with lower security settings? Did you see any difference? is the link points to any other site or the same site with a different page?

Comment: Ok, so I tested it with the security mode off (level at normal-high) and then it works. Now I wonder why.

Comment: It can be possible that any security setting is causing the issue. When you lower down the security level than possible that particular setting got disabled and the link in the iframe starts working. You can try to check those security settings one by one may help you to find that particular setting that is causing the issue here.